# C# How to check if downloaded zip archive is corrupted ('End of Central Directory record could not be found' exception thrown)

Tags: c#, .net, zip

I'm opening, unziping and reading file from remote share with followed code:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 2 << 18))
using (ZipArchive za = new ZipArchive(fs))
{
    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry zae in za.Entries)
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(zae.Open(), Encoding.GetEncoding(1251), true, 2 << 18))
    {
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            // reading logic
        }
    }
}
```

How to check if downloaded archive is corrupted?

Comment: First make sure size of download file is same size as original.  Then open with a zip utility manually to see if file is good.  The ZIP standard has a few different versions and no all zip tools support all versions.  Then I've seen issue where a ZIP is created on the Linux/Unix file server and then could not be opened after loaded on a Windows file system.  The zip files uses the partitioning and block size of the file system when zipping.  Then problems can occur when you unzip.  Also seen issue after more files are put into an existing zip and then read.  Again bugs in the zip utilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
bool ValidateZip(FileStream fs)
{
    using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
    {
        br.BaseStream.Seek(-22, SeekOrigin.End);
        return br.ReadUInt32() == 0x06054b50;
    }
}
```